# How to pass an array of formatted sentences to a Flask template?

Tags: python, templates, flask

I cannot figure how to pass an array of html-formatted sentences to flask template.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():
    question = request.form['question'].lower()
    text = request.form['text'].lower()

    open = '<div class="tooltip">'
    after_sentence = '<span class="tooltiptext">'
    close = '</span> </div>'

    out = text + " <mark> " +  question + " </mark>"

    return render_template('layout.html', text_out = tooltip, text_out2 = tooltip2)
```

and in template I have

```
  <div id="_out">

  {{text_out|safe}}

  {{text_out2|safe}}

 </div>
```

This works. But I want to format every sentence in a text (and i cannot hardcode it) (e.g provide tooltip with its own massage for every sentence) and pass it as array to the same template inside the same div. How would I go about it?

Smth like this gives template error

```
open = '<div class="tooltip">'
after_sentence = '<span class="tooltiptext">'
close = '</span> </div>'

tooltip = "first"
tooltip2 = "second"
first = open + "hello" + after_sentence + tooltip + close
second = open + "hello2" + after_sentence + tooltip2 + close
list = [first, second]
return render_template('layout.html', list)
```

and

```
  <div id="_out">

  <!-- {{text_out|safe}}

  {{text_out2|safe}} -->

  {% for item in {{list}} %}
  item 
  {% endfor %}

 </div>
```

Converting list to a dictionary does not help too

list = {"first":first, "second":second}
return render_template('layout.html', list)

gives me

```
TypeError: render_template() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Thank you

SOLVED: 
you need to pass dictionary and do

```
render_template("layout.html", dic=dic)
```

not

```
render_template("layout.html", dic)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this instead:

```
{% for item in list %}   
    {{ item|safe }} 
{% endfor %}
```

To break down some of the syntax here, `{% %}` generally refers to statements (like `{% if something %}` or `{% while True %}`). `{{ }}` is used when you want to print out something (like `{{ item }}` or `{{ text_out }}`). When you add a `|` to the print statement, it's directing jinja2 to apply a filter to the object immediately before it. For example, `|safe` means that the object mentioned before it is "safe" html and does not need to be escaped.

Comment: hmm I not getting anything in this case, no errors, but nothing is shown too

Comment: Actually i get error 
TypeError: render_template() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given